# How to Step Into import statement when Python debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

```
import numpy as np
```

is just calling `Includes/numpy/__init__`, right?

So, how to step into this while debugging? `F7` doesn't work. Setting breakpoint inside `numpy` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a script in a project in PyCharm where you import numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(100)
```

You need to find the __ init __ .py of numpy (for instance in site-packages/numpy/__ init __.py). You can find it in External Libraries/ site-packages. It should be located right below your project folder in PyCharm Project view.

Once you have located the file, open it and set a breakpoint at the first line of a code. Code starts like this:

```
try:
    __NUMPY_SETUP__
except NameError:
    __NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
```

To be able to reach the breakpoint in the __ init __.py of numpy, go back to the script and run it in the debug mode. This will bring you to the place in __ init __.py of numpy where the breakpoint is.

Comment: Can you explain what is it?